# Why doesn't context.drawImage() work in html canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to put the image file "sticky.png" into a canvas box, but all I'm getting is a blank canvas.  Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong and/or give me code that works?

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"
style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<body>

<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sticky = new Image();
sticky.onload = function() {
context.drawImage(sticky, 0, 0);
sticky.src = "sticky.png";
};


</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Draw it after the image has loaded. See here http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what I was doing wrong.  This is resolved now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the `sticky.src` before `sticky.onload`.

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var sticky = new Image();
sticky.src = "sticky.png";
sticky.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(sticky, 0, 0);
};

</script>
</body>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzm7m9zx/1/)

Comment: OMG. 8 hours were wasted until I found your answer. Save  God the people like you

Answer (score -1):

sometimes as a *workAround* we have to load the image before the canvas. It's very unusual, but it **WORKS**. And then you just hide the image. Don't forget to use setTimeOut to wait till image is loaded!

```js
setTimeout("paintStar()", 2000);

function paintStar() {
    var canva3 = document.getElementById('canvas3');
    canva3.width = 640;
    canva3.height = 480;
    var ct3 = canva3.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3DlDGTyfaFMtUf9GYykLglqfS8GzHbeKRV5vDfHraV1ihNIYo';

    ct3.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ct3.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 20, 20, 10, 200, 20, 20);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CANVAS</title>
    <style>
        .canvas-1 {
            width: 640px;
            height: 480px;
            border: 1px solid #777;
            
        }
        .img-1 {
            display: none;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="canva3.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="img-1"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3DlDGTyfaFMtUf9GYykLglqfS8GzHbeKRV5vDfHraV1ihNIYo" alt=""></div>
<canvas id="canvas3" style="border: 2px solid #444;">Doesn't work!</canvas>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My friend, check out the asynchronous api for the native Image element. Since you are setting the image.src without registering an onload callback, the canvas draw can sometimes occur before the browser prepares the image for rendition.